# Handle physical back button in Navigation Component with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have a simple proof of concept app that contains only 2 fragments: `MainFragment` and `RepositoryFragment` and 1 activity: `MainActivity`

Here's my `nav_graph`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/id_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/id_main"
        android:name="com.repofetcher.main.view.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainfragment_to_repositoryfragment"
            app:destination="@id/id_repo"
            app:popUpTo="@id/id_main"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/id_repo"
        android:name="com.repofetcher.repo.view.RepositoryFragment"
        android:label="{arg_repo_name}"
        tools:layout="@layout/repository_fragment">
        <argument
            android:name="arg_repo_name"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

MainActivity:

```
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (application as RepoFetcherApplication).appComponent.mainComponent().create().inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

Main activity's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.view.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the part that navigates from `MainFragment` to `RepositoryFragment`

```
    private fun navToRepositoryFragment(name: String) {
        findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainfragmentToRepositoryfragment(argRepoName = name))
    }
```

RepositoryFragment:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (requireActivity().application as RepoFetcherApplication).appComponent.repoComponent().create().inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.repository_fragment, container, false)
        dataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(RepositoryViewModel::class.java)
        dataBinding.viewModel = viewModel
        return dataBinding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.getRepository(args.argRepoName)
    }
```

Ideally, I would like to achieve these navigations:

navigating from `MainFragment` to `RepositoryFragment`, then by clicking either the back button on the `Toolbar` or on the device, it should navigate back to the `MainFragment`.

However in my case, only the back button on the toolbar will work as intended. The back button on the device will directly quit the app.

I wonder what I'm missing in the code?

## Update

One of the real problem behind this question is I used livedata for a single event (to handle the click event in order to navigate to `RepositoryFragment`).

So after taking a look at this article :
https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8

with solution @GabrieleMariotti provided and got the problem solved.

I would like to thank @GabrieleMariotti who helped me with great patient.

Comment: How do you navigate from MainFragment to RepositoryFragment?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I missed that part in my question, thanks for reminding. Question has been updated to include that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `app:popUpTo="@id/id_main"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true` in your `action`:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainfragment_to_repositoryfragment"
        app:destination="@id/nav_gallery"
        />
```

In your `onCreate` method use:

```
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

and in your `onSupportNavigateUp` method:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. However I've tried this before, it will result into a weird behaviour: after navigate to `RepositoryFragment`, then none of the back button (neither the one of the toolbar nor the device one) will not be able to do bring back `MainFragment`, it will stuck at `RepositoryFragment`

Comment: @dumbfingers Use the `appBarConfiguration`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)` in the source code already includes a default appBarConfiguration if you don't provide one: `fun AppCompatActivity.setupActionBarWithNavController(
    navController: NavController,
    configuration: AppBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
) {
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, configuration)
}`

Comment: I'm actually suspecting if I'm doing anything wrong in `RepositoryFragment`, I've updated the Question with the code of `RepositoryFragment`

Comment: nothing strange in RepositoryFragment. It should work

Comment: that's strange. It has the same "not be able to pop back to MainFragment" behaviour.

Comment: I know the reason why it didn't work. Because in MainFragment, the click event is a live data and that was not get cleared when the navigation finishes. So when pop back to MainFragment, the same "click event" will be observed and resulting another navigation to RepositoryFragment

Comment: But I still don't understand why the backbutton's behaviour is not the same when having `app:popUpTo="@id/id_main"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true` in navigation action?